# matplotlibやseabornで1次元散布図(horizontal)をふたつ描いて、共通の点の間に線を引きたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

seabornのviolinPlotで何とかなりますか？
以下の図を作るために、アドバイスいただけると助かります。

#入力データと作図結果
入力データ:
dataA=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
dataB=[3,6,9,12,15]

条件:
①　横線に〇をプロットする。以下の図は正確ではありません。水平線上にマーク〇をプロットする。
②　縦棒「|」を表示する。6と12が共通の値。

作図結果:
dataA  ――〇―――〇―――〇―――〇―――〇―――〇―――〇
縦棒  　　　　　　　　　　　|　　　　　　　　　　　　|
dataB  ――――〇―――――〇―――――〇―――――〇―――――〇

（次の行は不要です。説明用です。6と12の文字表示もできると、助かります。）
　　　１　２　３　4　5　　6　7　　0　　9　　0　1　2　3　4　　5

## 次のコードは、めちゃくちゃです。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: 質問タイトルが「seabornで1次元散布図(horizontal)を探しています。
」ですが、seabornでプロットしたい理由があるのですか？ また、「（次の行は不要です。説明用です。6と12の文字表示もできると、助かります。）」とありますが、それはグラフ内に表示したいという意味でしょうか？（共通数字の抽出は出来ますよね？）

Comment: グラフ内に表示したいです。matplotlib だけで済むなら,seabornをインストールしないので、助かります。

Comment: 情報は質問に追記お願いします。nekketsuuuさんの回答にて解決済でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> 縦棒を短くしたいです。

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections as mc
import seaborn as sns

dataA = [2, 4, 6,  8, 10, 12, 14]
dataB = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

data = [['dataA', v] for v in dataA] + [['dataB', v] for v in dataB]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data', 'value'])

plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 2.4))
ax = sns.stripplot(data=df, x='value', y='data', jitter=False, size=15)
hc = mc.LineCollection(
  [[[0, n], [i, n]] for n, i in enumerate(map(max, (dataA, dataB)))],
  colors='k', linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(hc)
lc = mc.LineCollection(
  [[[i, 0], [i, 1]] for i in set(dataA).intersection(dataB)],
  colors='red', linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.set_xlabel(''); ax.set_ylabel('')
for p in ('right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom'):
  ax.spines[p].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(
  left=False, bottom=False, labelleft=True, labelbottom=False)

for n, l in enumerate((dataA, dataB)):
  for i in l:
    ax.text(
      x=i+0.1, y=n-0.05, s=i,
      horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom',
      size='medium', color='k')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2 次元プロットの y 軸を表示しないことで 1 次元プロットに見せつつ、[`matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html) を使って共通部分に線を引けます。

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

def show_only_xaxis(ax):
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")
    ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
    data2 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

    xlim_left = min(min(data1), min(data2)) - 1
    xlim_right = max(max(data1), max(data2)) + 1
    for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
        show_only_xaxis(ax)
        ax.set_xlim(xlim_left, xlim_right)

    ax1.scatter(data1, np.zeros_like(data1))
    ax2.scatter(data2, np.zeros_like(data2))

    intersection = set(data1).intersection(data2)
    for x in intersection:
        con = ConnectionPatch(
            xyA=(x, 0),
            xyB=(x, 0),
            coordsA="data",
            coordsB="data",
            axesA=ax1,
            axesB=ax2,
            color="red",
        )
        ax2.add_artist(con)

    plt.show()
```

なお [`seaborn.violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) は確率分布の箱ひげ図と密度関数（の推定）を描くためのもので、全く関係ありません。

Answer (score 0):

> 何がしたいのかさっぱり分かりませんが、

申し訳ありません。説明不足でした。
追加の質問です。

(目的)
matplotlibで(整数問題)「2010年度 千葉大・医系数学 第4問」を作図してみたい。
(問題)
https://www.densu.jp/chiba/10chibampass.pdf#page=4
(解答)
https://www.densu.jp/chiba/10chibampass.pdf#page=9

次のコードは、「1次元散布図(1D scatter plot?)直し方を教えて下さい。」を参考にしました。
問題点①dataAとdataBが,重なっている。離したい。2段に表示したい。Y座標位置を、入力したい。
問題点②dataAとdataBを色分けしたい。
問題点③dataAとdataBの同じ値の箇所は、縦棒を表示したい。
問題点④数字81を、81(n=4)と表示したい。(又は、81の上に(n=4)と表示したい。任意の位置に文字を表示したい。
アドバイスをいただけると、助かります。

```
from sympy import *
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections as mc
import seaborn as sns

def My_1dScatterPlot(My_Name,dataA,my_color,my_Yzahyo):
    df = pd.DataFrame([[My_Name, v] for v in dataA], columns=['data', 'value'])

    plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 1))
    ax = sns.stripplot(data=df, x='value', y='data', jitter=False, size=8)
    hc = mc.LineCollection([[[0, 0], [max(dataA), 0]]], colors='k', linewidths=2)
    ax.add_collection(hc)

    for i in dataA:
      ax.text(
        x=i + 0.1, y=-0.01, s=i,
        horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom',
        size='medium', color='k')

def My_Nonlabel():
    ax.set_xlabel('');
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    for p in ('right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom'):
      ax.spines[p].set_visible(False)
    ax.tick_params(
      left=False, bottom=False, labelleft=True, labelbottom=False)

# 第4問(2)
var('colors coloru Yzahyos Yzahyou')
sahen=[3**i    for i in range(1, 5+1)]
uhen =[i**2-40 for i in range(7,17+1)]
My_1dScatterPlot('3**n'   ,sahen,colors,Yzahyos)
My_1dScatterPlot('k**2-40',uhen,coloru,Yzahyou)
My_Nonlabel
plt.show()

# # 第4問(1)
# # sahen = [3**i   for i in range(1,3+1)]
# # uhen = [i**3+1 for i in range(1,3+1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

追加の質問です。よろしくお願いします。
①dataAとdataBの間隔を狭くする(入力する）方法を教えて下さい。
　縦棒を短くしたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections as mc
import seaborn as sns

dataA = [2, 4, 6,  8, 10, 12, 14]
dataB = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

data = [['dataA', v] for v in (dataA)] + [['dataB', v] for v in (dataB)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data', 'value'])
ax = sns.stripplot(data=df, x='value', y='data', jitter=False, size=15)
hc = mc.LineCollection(
  [[[0, n], [i, n]] for n, i in enumerate(map(max, (dataA, dataB)))],
  colors='k', linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(hc)
lc = mc.LineCollection(
  [[[i, 0], [i, 1]] for i in set(dataA).intersection(dataB)],
  colors='red', linewidths=2)
ax.add_collection(lc)
for n, l in enumerate((dataA, dataB)):
  for i in l:
    ax.text(
      x=i+0.1, y=n-0.05, s=i,
      horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom',
      size='medium', color='k')
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(bottom=False,left=False,right=False,top=False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_xlabel("", size = "large", color ="green")
ax.set_ylabel("", size = "large", color="blue")
plt.show()
```